# Format GBP (or USD) to pence

Tags: php, number-formatting

Having difficulties formatting GBP to pence with `NumberFormatter::CURRENCY`.

Say we have £123.23, after format, it would be 12,323p

I can always multiple by 100 and format as `NumberFormatter::DECIMAL` and add `p` at the end.

However, I would presume there is a way to format to pence with a CURRENCY formater?

Comment: What in this find manual page did you not understand?, https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php

Comment: Pence is still Pound Sterling currency, multiply and add p.  Just like USD `$1.00` to `100¢`

Comment: @luuk I did not understand how to format input of 123.23 to output of 1,23.23p

Comment: Why are there only 2 numbers between the decimal separator (`.`) and the other separator? (`,`) ? I am used to decimal- and thousands- separator only. Is this some British thing?

Comment: @Luuk, can confirm it's not a British thing. additionally £123 in pennies is 12,300, not 1,230

Comment: It is still unclear how `£123.23` should be written as `1,23.23p`.  Because I would think `12,323p`  would be the way to way it.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code you are currently using. Is the input a number, or a string? What have you tried to resolve your problem?